# Python class membership and absolute paths

Tags: python, python-3.x, absolute-path, class-members

I'm working on a project where the source code is nested in the following structure:

```
|-- my-project
    |-- test_notebook.ipynb
    |-- package
        |-- src
        |    |-- module1.py    #defines MyClass
        |    |-- module2.py    #defines MyOtherClass 
        |    |-- some_other_modules.py
        |    |-- __init__.py
        |-- tests
             |-- some_modules.py
```

Now, the problem is as follows. `my_method` in `module1.py` is a method of `MyClass`. `my_method` looks as follows:

```py
from src.module2 import MyOtherClass

class MyClass:

    def my_method(self, list_of_objects: list):

        if all(isinstance(obj, str) for obj in list_of_objects):
            #do something

        elif all(isinstance(obj, MyOtherClass) for obj in list_of_objects):
            #do something else
    
        else:
            raise TypeError("This is a test")
```

If I create a list of `MyOtherClass` instances `o` inside `module1` itself and test `my_method`, then it works as expected: the `elif` clause is satisfied. However, if I create the same list of instances in `test_notebook.ipynb`, then the class of `o` is `<class package.src.module2.MyOtherClass>`. Thus, if I call `my_method`, then a `TypeError` is raised: Python (I'm using version 3.10) considers `<class package.src.module2.MyOtherClass>` to be different from `<class MyOtherClass>`.

```py
from package.src.module1 import MyClass
from package.src.module2 import MyOtherClass

obj1 = MyClass()

other_class_obj_1 = MyOtherClass()
other_class_obj_2 = MyOtherClass()
other_class_obj_3 = MyOtherClass()

result = obj1.my_method([other_class_obj_1, other_class_obj_2, other_class_obj_3])
```

The TypeError is raised:

```py
TypeError: This is a test
```

I tried rewriting the condition using the absolute path of `MyOtherClass`, as follows:

```
elif all(isinstance(obj, package.src.module2.MyOtherClass)) for obj in list_of_objects:
    #do_something
```

But that did not work, since Python is not able to resolve `package.src.module2.MyOtherClass`. Any idea how to solve this?

I'm adding the value of sys.path below:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/Users/my_name/Documents/Python_Projects/my-project/package', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python310.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
```

Comment: Could you try replacing `MyClass` with `type(self)` or just `self`? It's a bit dirty though

Comment: @Charalamm thanks for the suggestion! I realized that I didn't explain myself clearly though, so I rewrote the question

Comment: You need to include a complete [MCVE] for us to help here; for stuff involving import resolution, we'd need to see your `import` statements, and the value of `sys.path`.

Comment: How did you end up with two different classes named `MyOtherClass` in the first place?

Comment: @chepner Sorry for the confusion, but there is only one class MyOtherClass. I added more info to my post.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thank you for your feedback! I added import statements and the value of sys.path.

Comment: @mr_faulty: Yep, having edited those in, the problem is obvious. Just OOC, was my psychic debugging correct, and you're munging in the path into `sys.path` via the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, or was it something else?

Comment: @ShadowRanger thank you so much, your psychic debugging is correct! just out of interest, could you recommend some documentation on the PYTHONPATH variable?

Comment: @mr_faulty: Like [the stuff on the main Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)? It's not that interesting; it's just a hack used in place of properly creating installable packages. If you want to create proper installable packages, [a simple `setup.py` file is the way to go](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/index.html) (eventually `setup.cfg`-only packages are supposed to be supported, but they're not well-documented yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having posted your `sys.path` and `import` the problem is clear. Your `sys.path`, after the `''` (which has special meaning that's not relevant here) begins with:

```
'/Users/my_name/Documents/Python_Projects/my-project/package'
```

and does not at any point contain:

```
'/Users/my_name/Documents/Python_Projects/my-project'
```

This means that if you try to import with `import spam` or `from spam import eggs`, and it reaches that component of `sys.path` without finding it (likely unless it's found in the working directory, which can confuse things; you might see your code work fine if you ran Python interactively from `/Users/my_name/Documents/Python_Projects/my-project`, or if you ran a script located in that directory), it will be looking for a file named `/Users/my_name/Documents/Python_Projects/my-project/package/spam.py` (a module) or a directory named `/Users/my_name/Documents/Python_Projects/my-project/package/spam/` (a package).

**Your imports are asking for `from package.src.module1 import MyClass`, so the only way they'll be found in `/Users/my_name/Documents/Python_Projects/my-project/package` is if the rest of your files are in a subdirectory of `package` *also named `package`*.**

Two fixes are possible:

1. Change your imports to remove the `package.` prefix, e.g.:

   ```
   from package.src.module1 import MyClass
   from package.src.module2 import MyOtherClass
   ```

   becomes:

   ```
   from src.module1 import MyClass
   from src.module2 import MyOtherClass
   ```

   Probably not what you want, since `package` is a logical part of the module name, so we go to the other option.
2. Change whatever you're doing to modify `sys.path` (whether it's manual manipulation within the Python script, the hack of setting the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to point to that directory, hacking your `sys.path` via a custom `.pth` file in your `site-packages` directory, or some complicated IDE configuration that accomplishes a similar end result) so that instead of adding `'/Users/my_name/Documents/Python_Projects/my-project/package'` it adds `'/Users/my_name/Documents/Python_Projects/my-project'` (without the final `/package`). This will make the existing `from package.src.module1 import XXX` imports work, because now it will be scanning the `my-project` directory, not the `package` directory, looking for a directory named `package` (which `my-project` contains, and `package` does not).

   Psychic debugging says you're probably using `PYTHONPATH` hacks (if you were manually tweaking `sys.argv`, it's unlikely you'd remember to put it after the leading `''` entry, and all the other options are not as discoverable if you don't already know the import system by heart), e.g. you've got:

   ```bash
   export PYTHONPATH="$HOME/Documents/Python_Projects/my-project/package"
   ```

   in one of your shell config files (`~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, etc.) or you ran it manually in the shell you're running your code from, or possibly doing something similar in a Jupyter notebook configuration. So find wherever you're doing that, and trim off the `/package` component.

For the future, you probably want to make a proper `setup.py` and/or `setup.cfg` for your project so you can build a distribution package for it (source tarball or a wheel or the like) and *install* it properly with `python3 -mpip`, so that you don't rely on hacks like `PYTHONPATH` at all (it's not as awful as it used to be, now that few people use Python 2, but it's still an issue where it's completely unversioned and can be set in a million ways, so if you inadvertently have code there that's only syntactically valid in some versions of Python, e.g. any code with a variable or function or whatever named `async` in it stopped being legal Python in 3.7, you have to rewrite it to be perfectly portable, where properly installed modules can be installed separately for each version of Python, installed globally or per-user, or even isolated within virtual environments created by the `venv` or `virtualenv` packages).